# How to add map control with leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm struggling with turning on the Map Control in Leaflet.

Staring at the example doesn't seem to help.  I know I must be making a stupid mistake, but I can't figure it out.

http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/examples/layers-control.html

I've got my map, and it loads, displays ok, but at the `addTo(map)` method I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addTo' of undefined

Any ideas what I'm missing?

```
var osmUrl='http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
var osmAttrib='Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors';
var street_layer = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, {minZoom: 8, maxZoom: 18, attribution: osmAttrib});
map = new L.Map('map',{
                center: initial_center,
                zoom: initial_zoom,
                layers: mapLayersList    
});
var baseMaps = {"Streets": street_layer};
L.Control.Layers(baseMaps, null).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
L.Control.Layers(baseMaps, null).addTo(map);
```

is wrong. It is

```
L.control.layers(baseMaps, null).addTo(map);
```

You can check out the script's jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kidmenot/7sNcF/)